# empty a file while another process is writing

Tags: python, linux, shell

I wrote a python program to continously write to a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time

file = open("data",'w')

i = 1
while True:
    file.write("%d\n" % i)
    file.flush()
    i+=1
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

And after some time, the `data` file has some size other than 0. And then while the python write program is still running. I tried `echo "" > data` command to empty the existing contents. 
But it doesn't work. The file size still remains unchanged as soon as the python program keeps writing data to the file.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your file in `append` mode and use `truncate()` to delete old contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time

file = open("data",'a')
file.truncate()

i = 1
while True:
    file.write("%d\n" % i)
    file.flush()
    i+=1
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Then while this code is running you can do:

```
> data
```

from your shell to truncate the file at anytime to 0 byte **without null bytes getting added by file seek**.

Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode) causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at end-of-file thus avoiding the case of filling previous positions to null bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Normally files open for writing have exclusive access.
You cannot overwrite them while the opening application still has it open. You need to change your program to close and reopen after every write to make your scenario work.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the file after each write.
This will give other progs (umount, rm, mv, du) a fair chance to handle the data.
I am not sure about the overhead, the system caching might help you a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "" > data` does clear the file. Since the sleep duration inside the loop is 0.01s it immediately adds new content to the file.

This is visible here (the number of characters in the file reduces)

```
$ wc data
 4336  4335 27733 data
$ echo "" > data
$ wc data
  176   175 29848 data
```

This much clear if you increase the sleep duration

```
$ wc data
11 10 69 data
$ echo "" > data
$ wc data
 1 0 1 data
```

This is also visible in the file size decrease

```
$ ls -l data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 14 Sep  9 15:33 data
$ echo "" > data; ls -l data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1 Sep  9 15:33 data
```

Comment: yes, but the file size remains unchanged, how's that?

Comment: @richard.g The file size also decreases. How are you measuring the file size?